# Create a new console when I make a new class instance in Java

Tags: java, console

I want to be able to have multiple console outputs, one for the main class that I'm running and a second one for the new class that I'm initializing from within the main class, and I can't figure out how to do this in Java.

so for example when I run:

```
    Server server = new Server(true);
    server.start();
```

(server extends Thread) I want it to make a new console where its output will go, anyone know how to accomplish this?

Better worded: I want a new window where the System.out.printlns from server will go

Comment: You mean you want a window to pop up that behaves like `bash`?

Comment: I want a new window where the System.out.printlns from server will go

Comment: A single process can only have 1 System.out.

Answer (score 0):

If your server runs on a unix based system write the output of your server in an extra output.log file. Then you can open another bash and do the following command:

```
tail -f /path/output.log
```

It will show everything that is written into the log file.